# How can i remove every "<span" from items in my list? what should i change in regex?

Tags: python, regex

Code:

```
text2=re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', text)
```

Output:

```
['https://m.facebook.com/people/Vick-Arcadia/100009629167118/', 'https://m.facebook.com<span', 'https://m.facebook.com<span',
```

Answer (score 1):

In general [regexes aren't powerful enough to handle handle HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) which is tree structured and has matching openers and closers.

The preferred technique is to use a parser designed for HTML.  In the Python world, [lxml](https://lxml.de) and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) are popular choices.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work better

```
'https?:\/\/[\w\.]+(\/[\/\w-]+)?'
```

For regex I recommends testing on https://regex101.com/

But in operation on html better use BeautifulSoup lib, if u add more detals I can help u with this.